# Update dinâmico em componente Primefaces através do autocomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocompletar

Uma dúvida simples, existe alguma maneira fácil de utilizar o componente autocomplete do primefaces, e assim que ao selecionar alguma opção fazer com que um componente (por exemplo um dataScroller) seja atualizado???
Tentei algo através de um f:ajax adicionando um listener para o evento itemSelect como mostrado no showcase, mas não consigo prosseguir para fazer com que o outro componente seja atualizado dinamicamente, alguma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já usei o autocomplete, para atualizar outro componente usei:
`<p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="componenteID"/>`

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, era só isso mesmo, eu estava tendo problemas pois estava adicionando um listener ao evento ajax tentando criar alguma lógica com o itemSelect, sendo que nem é preciso.